# mongo insert record if exist or update the record in mongo using php

Tags: php, mongodb

i am new to mongodb and i am trying to write a cron file which will fetch records from my mysql and store it in mongo collection. Now what i want is i need to write another code which will check the mongo collection if it has that record or not  .if not means it has to insert or else update the record

my code is like this.

```
 $query="select * from tt";
 $result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
 while($fetch=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
 $uname=$fetch['name'];
 $lastname=$fetch['lastname'];
 $surname=$fetch['surname'];
 $age=$fetch['age'];

$document=array("name"=>$uname,"lastname"=>$lastname,"surname"=>$surname,"age"=>$age);
```

I want to check here whether the record is in mongo or not

```
$update = $collection->update($criteria,$document,array( 'upsert' =>true));
```

I don't know what to give in the -criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just use the $document as a criteria:

```
$collection->update($document, $document, ['upsert' => true]);
```

However if there is a unique index on some particular field, then you can use that field for the query.

Comment: yeah i tried that but it inserting a new record again.it is not updating anything.......

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $collection->updateOne(
  ['id' => $new->id],
  ['$setOnInsert' => $new],
  ['upsert' => true]
);
```

In this example if a record with the same id of $new exists it updates; else inserts document $new